# Is there a good reason to avoid upgrading a laptop to Windows 10 if it originally came with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Some reservations:
- My ultrabook has a recovery partition with **Windows 7** system files.
- I'm not sure how PC vendors generally deal with warranty related issues if you upgrade the OS.
- I have heard stories about people upgrading to Windows 10, experiencing issues, rolling back to Windows 7, and still experiencing issues.
- I have a backup disk image, but I've heard that some laptop vendors have BIOS/POST routines that are very picky about what they allow to boot over the disk, so I'm not sure if I'd be able to recover from that backup disk image, in the worst case.

At the same time, I feel like I'm missing out on future-proofing my ultrabook on at least the software side, if I don't upgrade to Windows 10.

What is the general recommendation for people with OEM Windows 7 laptops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem and would just try it. Do you even still have warranty considering the ultrabook still came with Windows 7?

If there are problems, you can always revert back to Windows 7 within 30 days (and later on upgrade again for free).

The features you've heard of are most likely related to Safeboot. This is something supported by Windows 10 out of the box, so you shouldn't have any problems with it either.

As long as you've got your backup, just give it a spin.